# Terraform Template_File Rendeding Not Working

Tags: terraform-template-file

I am new to Terraform and learning template_file with AWS. I just built a code as below with template_file but after launching the EC2 instance, I find that the script within template_file is not executed - tcpdump and httpd are not installed and hostname and nameserver configuration are not made. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

1. template_file: user_data.sh.tpl:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/bash
   sudo yum install -y tcpdump
   sudo yum update -y
   sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 php56-mysqlnd
   sudo service httpd start
   sudo hostname www.xyz.com
   echo "${nameserver}" >> /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
2. Resource and data in application.tf file under module dir:

   ```
   data "template_file" "user_data" {
   template = "${file("/Users/user1/Documents/Terraform/Code/started/modules/application/user_data.sh.tpl")}"

   vars {
   nameserver = "${var.external_nameserver}"
   }
   }

   resource "aws_instance" "app-server" {
   ami                    = "ami-b2b55cd5"
   key_name               = "privatekey"
   instance_type          = "${lookup(var.instance_type, var.environment)}"
   subnet_id              = "${var.subnet_id}"
   vpc_security_group_ids = ["${distinct(concat(var.extra_sgs, aws_security_group.allow_http.*.id))}"]
   user_data              = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"

   tags {
   Name = "${var.name}"
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Have a look in /var/log/messages and /var/log/cloud-init.log

Comment: you found the solution to this issue? please share.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `template_file`

```
user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
```

I used `templatefile` function (with filename `.tftpl` instead of `.tpl`) similar to this

```
templatefile("${path.module}/user_data.tftpl", {
  nameserver = "${var.external_nameserver}"
})
```

Then clean up and remove

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("/Users/user1/Documents/Terraform/Code/started/modules/application/user_data.sh.tpl")}"

  vars = {
    nameserver = "${var.external_nameserver}"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-template/issues/85
https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile